# Can't Create new entity in MongoDb - UPDATED

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ibm-cloud

I cannot create a new contact entity in MongoDb experimental in IBM Bluemix.
The code has worked before.

code looks like this;

```
**server.js**
var mongoose      = require('mongoose');
var config        = require('./server/config/config');
var appController = require('./server/controllers');

// https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4291
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.db.url);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
  console.info('Mongoose default connection open to ' + config.db.url);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
  console.error('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
 process.exit(0);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
  console.error('Mongoose default connection disconnected');
  process.exit(0);
});

**contact.js**
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: false },
  company: { type: String, required: false },
  email: { type: String, required: false },
  phone: { type: String, required: false }
},{ versionKey: false });

exports.Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);

**controller/api**
var Contact = require('../../models/contact').Contact;

exports.createContact = (req, res ) => {

  var contact = new Contact();
  contact.name = req.body.name;
  contact.company = req.body.company;
  contact.email = req.body.email;
  contact.phone = req.body.phone;

  contact.save( function( err, result ) {
    if( err ) {
      res.status(422).json( err );
    }
    else {
      res.status(200).json( result );
    }
  });
};

// THIS WORKS!!
exports.updateContactById = (req, res ) => {

  Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, 
    {'$set' : req.body}, {runValidators:true,new:true})
    .select( defaultProjection ) 
    .lean()
    .exec( function( err, contact ){    // Execute the query

    if( err ) {
      res.status(422).json( err );
    }
    else {
      res.status(200).json( contact );
    }
  });
};
`
```

I can see in the log in Bluemix that the connection fires a disconnected event when trying to call the contact.save() method.
*"Mongoose default connection disconnected"*

I'm using mongoose 4.6.5, Node version 4.6.0.

If I add console.log(contact.save) before the save call, I get in the log:

```
[Function: wrappedPointCut]
```

I have no clue what that is. However, I found this: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4064

**Problem**: The save() callback is not executed.

**UPDATE**
Now I get this error message:

```
[0;36mMongoose:[0m contacts.insert
({ 
_id: ObjectId("5814d8b7d617a6003a49a2fe"), 
name: [32m'Henrik'[39m, 
company: [32m'Henrik AB'[39m, 
email: [32m'henrik@henrik.com'[39m, 
phone: [32m'+46123456789'[39m, __v: [33m0[39m 
})
```

Now, I have started to believe it could be index problems. I have encounter that locally and when I can run mongod --repair and restarted, everything works locally.

Can I run mongod --repair in Bluemix?

**UPDATE2**
I removed the contact collection completely from the database and now the contact.save() callback function is executed, but, :-), I get a 422 error saying

```
name: MongoError message:1 to 159.8.128.163:10107 closed
```

In the log it looks like this;

```
console.log(contact.save) // [Function: wrappedPointCut]

[0;36mMongoose:[0m contacts.insert
({ 
_id: ObjectId("58150b01fb566d0038bf70e2"), 
name: [32m'henrik'[39m, 
company: [32m'henrik'[39m, 
email: [32m'henrik'[39m, 
phone: [32m'henrik'[39m, __v: [33m0[39m 
})

Mongoose default connection disconnected
```

Comment: This mongoDB service is experimental as you acknowledged. The catalog entry, in fact, says "It might not yet be stable and might change in ways that make it incompatible with earlier versions. This service is not recommended for production environments." If you want to use MongoDB, the Compose for MongoDB service is available on Bluemix: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/compose-for-mongodb/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I have realized that, since the database I use must have been corrupt.

A question, if I choose MongoDb by compose, do I have an admin client as well. Locally I use RoboMongo and I have set up an open source solution on Bluemix, do not remember the name, but I do not like it. It would be so nice with an interface to administer the database